# Chrome extension: script injection to workers and other nonpages

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Contentscripts don't seem to work for Worker, SharedWorker, ServiceWorker, and other nonpages.

Is there a simple way to inject a script into the start of them?

---

Sample contentscript runat docstart:

```
var script = document.createElement("script")
script.textContent = `
console.log = function() { return 0 }
alert(console.log) // overridden, good

var blob = new Blob([
  'console.log(Math.random())' // not overriden, bad
], { type: "text/javascript" })
var worker = new Worker(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
`
document.documentElement.appendChild(script)
```

---

Sure, it's possible to inject a script into the document itself and rewrite the constructors of Worker etc to include the script, but there had to be a simpler solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: Workers have their own global `self` object (just like `window` on normal pages) which exposes console functions. See the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope).

Comment: @wOxxOm, Hi, but how to inject a script into worker start without overriding `Worker` constructor?

Comment: Alas, I don't know.

Comment: Overriding the constructor sounds like the way to go.

Comment: @Makyen, Overriding the constructor doesn't work because of subresource-Integrity and trusted types